# Despite port 80 being unblocked apache still doesn't seem to work

Tags: wireless, networking, server, apache2, virtualbox-networking

I started installing at 19:30 and it's now 03:30. The OS is installed, apache is installed, I've unlocked the the var/www folder and moved my files there. I couldn't seem to host it. I then went through the port forwarding process and http://www.canyouseeme.org/ now says it can see port 80 whereas it couldn't before. 
I tried opening the ip on the browser of another computer. I tried all the ips from the ip addr command. I tried the ip from whatswhyip. I've tried the ip google gives when you type in my ip. I've tried the 'Home > Home Network > Devices > computer' ip my router gives. 
Anyone got any ideas what my issue is?

I should also probably say that it's a debian based server running on a virtual machine with 1Gb of memory

Answer (score 0):

Is the virtual machine connected to your network? if not maybe put the network setting in bridge mode. In this case the IP would be the one of the computer the virtual machine is running on.
Please give more details as to what you're doing, are you making a server for your local network? Or connected to the internet?

EDIT:

IT says [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) that if you want to run a server in a guest (which sounds like what you want to do) then bridged mode is the setting you have to use.

Comment: Yes it is connected to the internet. I'm using the ip address for the virtual machine (I think. I'm using the address from whatsmyip.org but I've also tried the ip addresses the terminal lists when you type ip addr. At the moment I'm trying to host a server from home to connect to the internet. At the moment it's just a few html pages.

Comment: Can you give your settings on how your virtual machine is connected to the newtwork?

Comment: Theses are the settings:http://gyazo.com/c1199307b78bca9a5013352705081bc4 The internet works within virtual box, I can open the web browser in the virtual box and use it.

Comment: Does it work when you take the ip from the virtual machine and you put it in a browser on your network? If not maybe check that apache is correctly installed and configured. Are the files owned by www-data in var/www?

Comment: No, but it does work on the browser on the server.

Comment: and what's the www-data? All the files I want hosting are in var/www

Comment: I ran these commands: sudo usermod -a -G www- data <quoole>

Comment: It doesn't matter if apache works on the server. So there's a problem with your network setttings then.

Comment: What kind of problem might their be?

Comment: Thank You so much! Changing the network settings to bridged worked!